# How to search in an array for the users input and print a certain text

Tags: javascript, button, input, popover

I trie to programm a website where the user has to to input a word from an array to get some output.The output is supposed to be a popup.

I trie to combine a function that compares the input to the array and another one that controls a popup.

The struggle is that the popup doesnt work. It could be that I some code is in the wrong place. Please have a look at it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundl.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="text.js" rel="text"></script>
        <scrpit src="p2.js" rel="javascript"></scrpit>
        <title>The history of Socks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="container">
            The history of Socks!
        </header>
            <div class="lb">Please type in a century including AC or BC!</div>
            <div class="modal">
                <div class="modal-dialog modal-content modal-header modal-body" id="print">
             </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" id="txt">
            <button type="button" id="bu" class="btn" onclick="checktxt()"></button>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="p2.js">Javascript</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="styles.css">style</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="text.js">Text</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
const array1 = ["1stcenturyBC", "2ndcenturyBC"]
const array2 = ["3rdcenturyAC", "4thcenturyAC"]

function checktxt() {
  let text;
  var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var response = document.getElementById("print");
  var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('.modal'), {})
  if (array1.includes(input)) {

  response.innerHTML = Text1;
  myModal.toggle()

    return function B() {
      var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-ba-toggle="popover"]'))
      var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
      })
    }
  }else if (array2.includes(input)){

    response.innerHTML = Text2;
    myModal.toggle()

    return function B() {
      var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-ba-toggle="popover"]'))
      var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
      })
    }
  }

}
```

```
const Text1 = "In the Greeks, piloî are socks made from mattet animal hair or skin.";
const Text2 = "The Romans weared a sock- sandal combination made out of leather and fabric strips essentails. They were used to keep their feet warm during battles. The poor weared foot wraps. The wealthy were enable to got fittes socks.";
```

Comment: I made you a snippet but had to fix the following: 1. `["1", "s"]]` - array elements have comma, not semicolons as delimiter. 2. You misspelled getElementByID. 
The script works now . You need to click [edit] and make it a [mcve]. The bootstrap stuff does nto work with what you have posted so far

Comment: `console.log(array1.includes(input))` does not return a boolean. You want to test  `if (array1.includes(input))` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const array1 = ["1", "s"]

function checktxt() {
  let text;
  var input = document.getElementById("txt").value;
  var response = document.getElementById("print");
  var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.querySelector('.modal'), {})
  if (array1.includes(input)) {
  
  response.innerHTML = input;
  myModal.toggle()
  
    return function B() {
      var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-ba-toggle="popover"]'))
      var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-content modal-header modal-body" id="print">
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="txt">
<button type="button" id="bu" class="btn-primary" onclick="checktxt()">Check Text</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Why does it not work in my codespace?

Comment: @user40089 i dont know, maybe something prevents it? its working here

Comment: I can't find the problem. Is it okay if i write my html code in the next comment and you have a look at it?

Comment: just edit the question and add all at one place

Comment: Please have a look at it now.

Comment: @well its working, shows, Text1 when input is 1stcenturyBC or 2ndcenturyBC

Comment: `<button type="button" id="bu" class="btn" onclick="checktxt()">Check Text</button>`